# How do you develop a microservice in isolation when it depends on other microservices?

Tags: microservices

We are evaluating a move to microservices.  Each microservice would be its own project developed in isolation.  During planning, we have determined that some of the microservices will communicate with other via REST calls, pub/sub, messaging (ie. a order service needs product information from product service).

If a microservice depends on retrieving data from another microservice, how can it be run in isolation during development?  For example, what happens when your order service requests product details, but there is nothing to answer that request?

Comment: http://www.mbtest.org/

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is an stub rest service. Create a webapp that takes the expected output using a path that is not part of the public api. When you invoke the public api it sends what it just received

Comment: By public I mean the paths that are going to be part of the micro services conversation. the same applies to the other channels of messaging

Comment: I think I understand.  We'd develop a client application next to the microservice that could generate fake events or answer REST requests so that we can trigger things as needed and flex parts of the microservice and debug.  Does this sound correct?  Thanks for your helpful answer.

Comment: Yes, but not client only the other microservices can be smart to know when the "mock" path has been invoked to send dummy data. You can even feed the events' data to the mock service via a browser to avoid having to code it (at least before you are ready to make it part CI, formal test runs)

Comment: @efekctive I think the problem is in the design and how to make services properly decoupled, but not in how to mock a service. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @IlliakaillI my answer does not preclude any of the above. But feel free to help the poster.

Comment: @efekctive Oh, thank you for allowing me to do that, this is very nice of you ;)

Answer (score 2):

> If a microservice depends on retrieving data from another microservice, how can it be run in isolation during development?

It should be **always** temporally isolated from other services during development and production as well.

> For example, what happens when your order service requests product details, but there is nothing to answer that request?

This is a place where design flaw reveals itself: order service **should not** request product details from another service. Product details should be stored in the message (event) that order service will be subscribed to. Order service should be getting this message in an asynchronous manner using publish-subscribe pattern and saving it in its own database. Data about the product will be stored in 2 places as the result of that.

Please consider reading [this series of articles](https://www.tigerteam.dk/2014/micro-services-its-not-only-the-size-that-matters-its-also-how-you-use-them-part-1/) about microservices for more details. But in a nutshell: your services should be temporally decoupled, so when your product service is down - order service can continue its operations without interruptions. This is the key thing to understand about good distributed systems design in general.

Comment: Good point about avoiding request/response.  We are still struggling with how to develop effectively in this scenario.  If developing service A that subscribes to events of B, how do developers test features of A without standing up instance of B to produce events?

Comment: Also, we are using a REST service to abstract away interaction with very bad parts of a legacy system.  I'm now realizing this will be trouble later!  Interesting problem since it's impossible to make the old system event-driven.

Comment: @kenchilada testing is pretty simple with pub-subscribe: you just publish testing events from your tests into a bus/eventstore. Your SUT service will 'think' that they are coming from another parts of the system even without using fakes.

Comment: @kenchilada and by the way, it is possible to make old systems to emit events, and new systems will consume those events. It is actually the easiest way to refactor legacy system bit by bit.